# How can I remove lines that do not match a pattern?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I want to remove lines from a variable that does not match a pattern and save output to another variable using PowerShell.

Consider variable `$value` with contents:

```
"1609.68956.43566"
"1699809.89.412"
"1699.68.436"
"1699809.956.6"
"Heloo\this is"
"HI"
```

The requirement is to remove all lines except matching pattern "16*"

Expected output

```
"1609.68956.43566"
"1699809.89.412"
"1699.68.436"
"1699809.956.6"
```

Tried searching around but could not locate the commands

Comment: What have you tried, and how has what you've tried failed? Ideally, you should provide a [MCVE] of what you've tried, and include specific information on how it failed, with error messages and/or erroneous output. [SO] is not a code-writing service; the best questions are those which provide useful information so that those who answer can guide you to devising your own correct answer. See [Ask] a Good Question.

Comment: Allow me to direct your attention towards PowerShell's [comparison operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-3.0).

Answer (score 0):

Now I did this on Powershell v5 so if this doesn't work on Powershell v2... oops.  Anyway you should able use RegEx to match a pattern.

```
$newvariable = $value -match "^16"
```

This will assign the matching values from `$value` to `$newvariable`; `"^16"` tells it to match anything starting with 16, it won't match anything that starts with anything else (so e.g. 2016 won't match).

Comment: i am getting output as false

Comment: What version of PowerShell are you using?  This is working fine for me.  Are you in the ISE or the console?